# Помогите найти неявную ошибку

Tags: сортировка, pascal, pascalabc.net

Вот программа, её задача - сортировать строки по алфавиту, но она их не сортирует. Помогите найти, в чём погрешность.

```
const
  pi = 5;

type
  ar = array[1..5]of string;

function bool(s001, s002: string): boolean;
begin
  result := s001 < s002;
end;

var
  i: integer;
  s, s1: string;
  a: ar;
  c1, c2: integer;

procedure bubble(var a: ar);
var
  i, i2: integer;
  s, s2: string;
  c1, c2: char;
begin
  for i := 1 to pi - 1 do
    for i2 := 1 to pi - i2 do
    begin
      if bool(a[i], a[i + 1]) then
      begin
        s2 := a[i2];
        a[i2] := a[i2 + 1];
        a[i2 + 1] := s2;
      end
    end;
end;

begin
  for i := 1 to pi do
  begin
    writeln('Введите ', i, ' элемент массива:');
    readln(s);
    a[i] := s;
  end;
  for i := 1 to pi do
  begin
    writeln(a[i]);


  end;
  bubble(a);
  writeln('_________________');
  for i := 1 to pi do
  begin
    writeln(a[i]);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Учитесь заниматься отладкой сами. Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: pi - зарезервированное имя переменной. Или я не прав?

Comment: В pascal.ABC pi - это константа, в отличие от Delphi, , где pi - это функция. Но, поскольку к зарезервированным именам pi не относится, вы можете сколько угодно переопределять pi что там, что там.

Comment: @Kromster Отладка здесь бесполезна, на мой взгляд (ну, разве что, действительно, имели место быть опечатки). Нужно брать карандаш и лист бумаги, и рисовать алгоритм.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov отладка алгоритма нужна в том числе тоже ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас либо непонимание метода пузырька, либо опечатки. 
**Первая:**

```
for i2 := 1 to pi - i2 do
```

Очень странная конструкция. Вам же второй цикл надо проводить так:

```
for i2 := 1 to pi - i do
```

**Вторая:**

```
if bool(a[i], a[i + 1])
```

вы сравниваете не те члены массива строк, нужно:

```
if bool(a[i2], a[i2 + 1])
```

То есть, правильный цикл будет выглядеть так:

```
procedure bubble(var a: ar);
var
  i, i2: integer;
  s, s2: string;
  c1, c2: char;
begin
  for i := 1 to pi - 1 do
    for i2 := 1 to pi - i do
    begin
      if bool(a[i2], a[i2 + 1]) then
      begin
        s2 := a[i2];
        a[i2] := a[i2 + 1];
        a[i2 + 1] := s2;
      end
    end;
end;
```

Тогда всё работает. Но учтите, что сортировка в вашем случае идёт по убыванию, потому как фунция `bool` возвращает истину именно для убывания.

P.S. Если используете константу pi как размер массива, то и сам массив надо бы объявить через неё:

```
type
  ar = array[1..pi]of string;
```